# How to calculate time difference in R using an dataframe

Tags: r, time

Have an large data frame where there's 2 columns (POSIXct) and need to calculate length of ride.

Dates are formatted as follows:

format: "2020-10-31 19:39:43"

Can use the difftime function, correct?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: As long as the colums are of the type datetime you can use difftime!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

Given your data is using the correct POSIXct format you can simply subtract two dates to get the difference. No need for additional functions.

```
date1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2020-10-31 19:39:43", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
date2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2020-10-31 19:20:43", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))

date1 - date2
```

Output: *Time difference of 19 mins*

Comment: Thanks. what if I need the output format to be 00.00.00

Comment: POSIX can only store date data with / or - seperators. However, if you treat the date as a string you can simply modify your output (with gsub() for example) prior to displaying it. like this: `print(gsub("-", ".", date2))` The first parameter is yor search term "-", while the second specifies what it should be replaced with ".", the third is your string.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what output format you want.
For example if you want month difference between two dates, you can use the "interval" function from library "lubridate"

```
library(lubridate)
interval(as.Date(df$date1),as.Date(df$date2) %/% months(1))
```

It also works with years, weeks, days, hours